# Match multiple words anywhere in string

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to check if all words in a string `selection` are present in another string. There will be an arbitrary number of words. This is not an OR. All words MUST be present in the matcher. Order does not matter. For example, when `selection` is `"John Zeni"`, it must match `" John Paul Zeni"` because both `"John"` and `"Zeni"` are in the matcher. If `selection` was just `"John"`, then it should match, but since there are multiple words, all words must match. Regex solution is required.

This is what I tried:

```
selection = "John Zeni"
pattern = selection.split(" ").join("|")
# => "John|Zeni"
/#{Regexp.quote(pattern)}/
# => /John\|Zeni/ 
" John Paul Zeni".match(/#{Regexp.quote(pattern)}/)
# => nil
```

Why doesn't it match? The problem is with `Regexp.quote` I think. It is important that both words match in the matcher. This also should not match:

```
" John Paul Zeni" =~ /(John|Zach)/ 
# => 1
```

Comment: Check all name parts individually: `selection.split(" ").all?{|name| str.include?(name)}`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I need a regex solution, because ultimately I have to put this in a Mongoid query which requires regex.

Comment: Use lookaheads: `^(?=.*John)(?=.*Zeni)`

Comment: Why use `Regexp.quote`? Do you have special chars to account for?

Comment: "which requires regex." - not necessarily. Even in mongodb, you can combine invidual clauses with `$and`

Comment: Try `pattern = Regexp.new("(?m)\\A(?=.*\\b#{selection.split(/\s+/).join("\\b)(?=.*\\b")}\\b)")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I'm not too well-versed in regex but doesn't this pattern assume word order? All examples show ordered match, but it's not explicitly specified in the question. :shrug:

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It creates the [`(?m-ix:\A(?=.*\bJohn\b)(?=.*\bZeni\b))`](https://regex101.com/r/QHj6kN/2) regex. It checks for the items (whole words) in any order.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev order does not matter

Comment: I just read your comment about a regex being required. If so, that should be stated in the question itself.

Comment: @CarySwoveland it is stated now.

Comment: Could you work around the problem using lookaheads?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev something like this would work in mongodb: Contact.where(name: /John/).and(name: /Zeni/). But I am dealing with an arbitrary number of words.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, do you need the anchor `\A` in your regex? Note that you are missing a double quote in `join`. I suggest you post this as an answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland All double quotes are there. The code is tested and working. Yes, `\A` is very important, it makes the engine check for these requirements only once.

Comment: @Wictor, I misread the `join`. Could you elaborate on your second sentence (and please do so in an answer)? I assume one is using, say, `match?`. If the string is multiline does the regex engine not check each lookahead in turn, searching the entire string for a match (without `\A`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use positive lookaheads to simulate `AND`:

```
string = "Paul Zach"
re = '^(?=.*' + string.split(/\s+/).map{ |x| Regexp.quote(x) }.join(')(?=.*') + ')'
"John Paul Mak Zach Jack Zen" =~ /#{re}/
```

If matching through multiple lines is a need, enable `m` flag or use `[\s\S]` instead of `.`. You can ensure that words are not within other words using `\b` token around them.

Note: Order doesn't matter.

Comment: You may wish to generalize this so that it would work with an arbitrary number of words that must be contained in the string.

Comment: Thank you. I may leave the code part alone since I don't Ruby.

Comment: Yes @CarySwoveland is right. There will be an arbitrary number of words. It will not always be two. That is why I was trying to incorporate Regexp.quote.

Comment: @Donato If you are not sure about words, I used `map` to apply `Regexp.quote` for each word.

Comment: You need word breaks so that `"Paul"` in `string` won't match `"Paula"` in the test string.

Answer (score 4):

```
("John Zeni".split - "John Paul Zeni".split).empty?
  #=> true
```

If `str` may contain punctuation we should remove those characters before splitting.

```
("John Zeni Lola".split - "John Lola Paul, Zeni.".gsub(/[[:punct:]]/,'').split).empty?
  #=> true
```

Comment: Do you think OP doesn't want to find a match on `John Paul,Zeni`?

Comment: @revo, if the string may contain punctuation I would suggest those characters be removed as a pre-processing step (`str.gsub(/[[:punct:]]/, '')`). One may also want to downcase or upcase everything. If one were instead using a regex that might not be necessary but doing so would simplify the regex.

Comment: You may wish to generalize this so that it would work on arbitrary word separators.

Comment: The last sentence of the question ("Regex solution is required.") was added after I posted my answer.

Comment: Yes, but first two sentences never changed.

Comment: While this is a better answer and deserves a +1, which I gave it, I really needed a regex in my case.